# Limit of an integral: Possible issue with uniform integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{ne^x\cos x}{1 + n^2x^2}$. I have an integral $\int\limits_0^1f_n$ whose limit I would like to find as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I've tried using Lebesgue Dominated Convergence, Vitali Convergence, and even Bounded Convergence, but unfortunately in all three cases, I run into the problem that the $f_n$ becomes unbounded at 0, so I don't think $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable on [0, 1].

Could anyone provide a hint? (Or perhaps rectify my understanding of uniform integrability...)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y = nx$. Then

$$\int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx = \int_0^n \frac{e^{y/n} \cos(y/n)}{1 + y^2}\, dy = \int_0^\infty g_n(y)\,dy$$ with $$g_n(y)=\frac{e^{y/n} \cos(y/n)}{1 + y^2}  1_{[0,n]}(y).$$

We have for $y \geqslant 0$

$$\left| g_n(y)\right| \leqslant eg(y) = \frac{e}{1+y^2}.$$
 and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}g_n(y)=g(y).$$

Since $g$ is integrable you can now apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^\infty g_n(y)\, dy = \int_0^\infty \frac{dy}{1+y^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Very clean, +1.

Comment: That substitution really cleaned things up! Also, when going through this problem, how did you know that making the integral go to infinity would be necessary? Was it the $\frac{1}{1 + y^2}$ factor that gave it away?

Comment: @d4rk_1nf1n1ty: That was a clue, but since we are letting the dominated convergence theorem do the heavy lifting here I just needed to adapt to the hypotheses of that theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g_n(x) = \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$. Then $c g_n \leq f_n \leq Cg_n$ on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 g_n(x)\,dx = \arctan(n)$. Also notice that $g_n \to 0$ but $arctan(n) \to \frac{\pi}{2}$,
Since the $f_n$ are very similar, we should not expect $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx$ to converge to $\int_0^1 0\,dx$. In fact, we know $\limsup_n\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx \geq c\lim_n \int_0^1 g_n(x)\,dx = c \frac{\pi}{2} \neq 0$, so we definitely can't use any of the standard convergence theorems.

Instead, consider $g_n-f_n$. I'll leave it to you to show that $g_n-f_n$ is uniformly integrable (in fact uniformly bounded, compute the derivative to find its maximum and show the max goes to zero with $n$), and hence $\lim_n\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx = \lim_n\int_0^1g_n(x)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: This is a nice "direct" answer. +1

Comment: Beautiful! I'll take a look at $g_n - f_n$ to show it's uniformly integrable. Thanks for pointing out why none of the standard convergence theorems could be used, as well!  When you initially saw this problem, what were some big hints concerning how to approach this problem, especially if none of the standard theorems could be used here?